# How to convert a string to a decimal number in specified format in SQL(Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column of type varchar having following values

```
Values in column     Output should be
000025               00.25
002340               23.40
239044               2390.44
000305               3.05
000100               1.00
```

when i am using to_number I am getting a plain number (like 25,2340,239044 ) but i need it in above specified decimal number.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why does the first one have two zeros before the decimal point, but the other don't have leading zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
select cast(to_number(val) / 100 as decimal(5, 2))
```

Comment: this will give 000100  as 1. I needed it like 1.00

Comment: @GauravAgrahari . . . If you want decimal places, use either `to_char()` or convert to a decimal/numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first value is only supposed to have one leading zero, you can convert the original string to a number, divide by 100, and then format it back to a string using a model that matches your desired output, e.g.:

```
to_char(to_number(orig_str)/100, '9990.00') as new_str
```

Demo:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table(orig_str) as (
  select 000025 from dual
  union all select 002340 from dual
  union all select 239044 from dual
  union all select 000305 from dual
  union all select 000100 from dual
)
-- query
select orig_str,
  to_char(to_number(orig_str)/100, '9990.00') as new_str
from your_table;

  ORIG_STR NEW_STR 
---------- --------
        25     0.25
      2340    23.40
    239044  2390.44
       305     3.05
       100     1.00
```

If you want the alignment as shown in the question, with all the values left-aligned instead of aligned on the decimal point, you can add [the `FM` format modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-A4CCA8BD-1679-432E-96BA-22FB46FF23E0), which suppresses the padding spaces:

```
select orig_str,
  to_char(to_number(orig_str)/100, 'FM9990.00') as new_str
from your_table;

  ORIG_STR NEW_STR 
---------- --------
        25 0.25    
      2340 23.40   
    239044 2390.44 
       305 3.05    
       100 1.00
```